# New EC2 servers unavailable via Public IP's

Tags: amazon-vpc

I've created a new VPC with the 172.21.0.0/16 subnet. I proceeded to launch an instance into it with a public IP.

Unfortunately the instance does not come online. Instances that I launch in another VPC/subnet do work fine.

I thought instances with a public IP would always have working internet functionality in AWS.

Do I have to reconfigure the VPC?

Comment: AWS has private and public subnets. Does your subnet have an IGW (internet gateway)?